# Classify users of a network based an a variable

Tags: statistics

I've a variable for my users in a social network.

Now I want to classify them into $4$ or $5$ classes.

The variable value is uniformly in $[0,1]$.

My users have the following property:

- Standard Deviation $\approx 0.28$
- Average of the value $\approx 0.49$
- Maximum number $= 0.99$
- Minimum number $\approx 0.00007$

Is there any general solution to classify them into 4 or 5 classes such as RICH, POOR, SEMIRICH, SEMIPOOR?

Thank you

Comment: So that each class has roughly the same amount of people?

Comment: @KennyLau Yes. For example from 15000 users, 3200 users have detected as POOR based on the variable

Comment: If the variable value is uniform, how come the average value is not $0.50$?

Comment: @KennyLau because it is an empirical average.

Comment: It is a variable which is chosen uniformly from [0,1]

Comment: Actually I want to use the variable for finding TruePositive and FalsePositive measures.

Comment: Maybe just divide in regular intervals since the variable is uniform? E.g. 0~0.25, 0.25~0.5, 0.5~0.75, 0.75~1

Comment: Is it a good way to classify them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your 'properties' are consistent with data from $UNIF(0,1).$ (Such quantities from data are seldom exactly the same as for the population distribution, but
yours are close. For example, the population SD is $\sqrt{1/12} =  0.2887.$)

Presumably, you want to use this variable to classify users into four categories. So you need
three 'cut points' in $(0,1)$ to make the classification. The three quartiles
of $UNIF(0,1)$ are .25, .5 and  .75. Lacking any information for better
cutpoints, those are the ones I would use. (That would tend to put 1/4 of the
users into each of the four categories.)

Alternatively, the four quintiles of standard uniform are .2, .4, .6, and .8; you could use those if you wanted *five* roughly equally-populous categories.